# Simple boxes graph using Gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, histogram, graphing

I have a data file called for example dat.txt

0 3111 1755 2577 1895 3224 1725 2163 1641 2525 331

it's got a single line of data and for some reason i wanna plot them as vertical boxes for each value, rather than a line connecting all of the data points.

How can i do that with Gnuplot please, I think the version im stuck with for gnuplot is 4.2.6

Answer (score 0):

What about `help boxes` or searching for boxes in the documentation? So, for boxes, use the `boxes` plotting style.

In any case, you must have your data organized in columns rather than as single row. On *nix you can do that on-the-fly with `tr`:

```
set style fill solid
set boxwidth 0.9
plot '< tr " " "\n" < dat.txt' with boxes
```

The output, with version 4.2.6 is:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, got the boxes, trying to figure out how to change the color to black or grey.

Comment: `plot '< tr " " "\n" < dat.txt' with boxes lc rgb '#aaaaaa'`